# PHP file_get_contents multiple times for the same file

Tags: php

With [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) in PHP, what happens if I use it on the same file twice?

Is it intelligent enough to only load the file once and simply refer to the result of the first call on subsequent calls; or do I need to implement something like that myself?

In the docs it has a line that says this, but I don't really understand what it means or whether it's related:

> It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

I'm not sure how to prepare a test case to work this out for myself, so any information around how I could do that would also be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll read the file twice. If you want the same content twice, put it in a variable as a matter of good practice anyways.

Comment: I thought so, but it seemed like something that PHP would have been smart enough to take care of to avoid people spamming it. Also I was confident that this would be a duplicate but I couldn't find anything. If you do (being a moderator) then let me know.

Comment: @MartyWallace: Well, it's really impossible to tell in general; anything could happen between file reads, or the file could be too big to cache, or it could be a socket/pipe, etcetera. It would never be reliable and just isn't worth it when developers can tell the program exactly what to do :) [And it's not a duplicate, as far as I can tell by searching.]

Comment: But if PHP would cache this it would cause problems, if you change the file (e. g. thru an ajax call or whatever) and want to be able to reload the file.