# Does file_get_contents use a cache?

Tags: php, file-io

I have a function that generates a table with contents from the DB. Some cells have custom HTML which I'm reading in with file_get_contents through a templating system.

The small content is the same but this action is performed maybe 15 times (I have a limit of 15 table rows per page). So does file_get_contents cache if it sees that the content is the same?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: file_get_contents is basically just a shortcut for fopen, fread, fclose etc - so I imagine opening a file pointer and freading it isn't cached.

Comment: Is there a file reading function in PHP where I can choose `$cache = true`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888087/php-file-get-contents-multiple-times-for-the-same-file

Comment: readfile() function seems to support caching - http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708332/does-file-get-contents-use-a-cache

please refer it also. That will be helpful to you.

Comment: @VladimirHraban readfile can't store contents in a $variable

Comment: @silkfire It will if you use output buffer :) ob_start(), ob_get_contents(), ob_end_clean();

Comment: @VladimirHraban Don't like using the ob_ functions, sorry.

Answer (score 9):

`file_get_contents()` does not have caching mechanism. However, you can use write your own caching mechanism.

Here is a draft :

```
$cache_file = 'content.cache';
if(file_exists($cache_file)) {
  if(time() - filemtime($cache_file) > 86400) {
     // too old , re-fetch
     $cache = file_get_contents('YOUR FILE SOURCE');
     file_put_contents($cache_file, $cache);
  } else {
     // cache is still fresh
  }
} else {
  // no cache, create one
  $cache = file_get_contents('YOUR FILE SOURCE');
  file_put_contents($cache_file, $cache);
}
```

**UPDATE** the previous `if` case is incorrect, now rectified by comparing to current time. Thanks @Arrakeen.

Comment: PHP has a native support of caching called APC - http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Comment: So... you're caching the contents of a file in a file...?!?!

Comment: This actually will make it slower.

Comment: Here's an interesting article about `file_get_contents()` and `APC`: https://blogs.oracle.com/basant/entry/caching_file_get_contents_output

Comment: @Gerry not really, if the file source is from network, it will make it faster

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I am afraid the link to the patch provided in the article is broken :-( Is there an alternative?

Comment: This would work if the `filemtime()` function would be properly compared with the current time, in fact in this example `if(filemtime($cache_file) > 86400)` will always be `true`.

Answer (score 4):

Like @deceze says, generally the answer is no. However operating system level caches may cache recently used files to make for quicker access, but I wouldn't count on those being available. If you'd like to cache a file that is being read multiple times per request, consider using a static variable to act as a cache inside a wrapper function.

```php
function my_file_read($filename) {
  static $file_contents = array();
  if (!isset($file_contents[$filename])) {
    $file_contents[$filename] = file_get_contents($filename);
  }
  return $file_contents[$filename];
}
```

Calling my_file_read($filename) multiple times will only read the file from disk a single time, subsequent calls will read the value from the static variable within the function. Note that you shouldn't count on this approach for large files or ones used only once per page, since the memory used by the static variable will persist until the end of the request. Keeping the contents of files unnecessarily in static variables is a good way to make your script a memory hog.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is yes. All the PHP file system functions do their own caching, and you can use the "realpath_cache_size = 0" directive in PHP.ini to disable the caching if you like. The default caching timeout is 120 seconds. This is separate from the caching typically done by browsers for all GET requests (the majority of Web accesses) unless the HTTP headers override it. Caching is not a good idea during development work, since your code may read in old data from a file whose contents you have changed.

Comment: `realpath_cache_size` only caches real pathes of the files, not results of file reading operations. More detailed at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath-cache-size.php#101840