# Does file_get_contents use cache? If it does how do I prevent?

Tags: php, laravel

With this code :

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $times; $i++){
    $milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    $res = file_get_contents($url);
    $milliseconds2 = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

    $milisecondsCount = $milliseconds2 - $milliseconds;
    echo 'miliseconds=' . $milisecondsCount . ' ms' . "\n";
}
```

I get this output :

```
miliseconds=1048 ms
miliseconds=169 ms
miliseconds=229 ms
miliseconds=209 ms
....
```

But with sleep:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $times; $i++){
    $milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    $res = file_get_contents($url);
    $milliseconds2 = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

    $milisecondsCount = $milliseconds2 - $milliseconds;
    echo 'miliseconds=' . $milisecondsCount . ' ms' . "\n";
    sleep(2);
}
```

This :

```
miliseconds=1172 ms
miliseconds=1157 ms
miliseconds=1638 ms
....
```

So what is happening here ?

Comment: after echo try `unset($res)` in for loop...

Comment: this is not helping...

Comment: Maybe server itself caches some content that serves URL?

Comment: where does your stream come from? Explain `stream_context_create($arrContextOptions)` as a source.

Comment: Same results without $arrContextOptions.

Comment: Read this answer to almost exactly the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20768101/3536236

Comment: when i use `unset($res) or $res = null` i don't see so much spikes in time

Comment: Is this `$url` a local or a remote file? For local files PHP does cache the information returned by the `stat` system call, you can clear it with clearstatcache, and the contents is cached by your operating system.

Comment: @fico7489 I meant what sort of stream is it, your answer didn't shine any light.

Comment: I see, OS caching is probably  issue here...

Comment: $url is localhost url: eg. http : // localhost/something

Comment: Is localhost on your filesystem or is it a local remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My questions:**

1) Why don't you test this yourself by using `clearstatcache` and checking the time signatures with and without using it?

2) Your method of testing is terrible, as a first fix - have you tried swapping so that the "sleep" reading function plays first rather than second?

3) How many iterations of your test have you done?
If it's less than 10,000 then I suggest you repeat your tests to be sure to identify firstly the average delay (or lack thereof) and then what makes you think that this is caused specifically by caching?

4) What are the specs. of your machine, your RAM and free and available memory upon each iteration?

5) Is your server live? Are you able to remove outside services as possible causes of time disparity? (such as anti-virus, background processes loading, server traffic, etc. etc.)?

**My Answer:**

- [Short answer, is NO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097432/does-file-get-contents-use-a-cache) `file_get_contents` does not use the cache.

> However, operating system level caches may cache recently used files to
>   make for quicker access, but I wouldn't count on those being
>   available.
>
> Calling a file reference multiple times will only read the file
>   from disk a single time, subsequent calls will read the value from the
>   static variable within the function. Note that you shouldn't count on
>   this approach for large files or ones used only once per page, since
>   the memory used by the static variable will persist until the end of
>   the request. Keeping the contents of files unnecessarily in static
>   variables is a good way to make your script a memory hog.

Quoted from [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20768101/3536236).

- For remote (non local filesystem) files, there are so many possible causes of variable delays that really `file_get_contents` caching is a long way down the list of options.
- As you claim to be connecting using a `localhost/` reference structure, I would hazard (but not certain) that your server will be using various firewall and checking techniques to check the incoming request which will add a large variable to the time taken.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate a random query string with url.
For eg: `$url = 'http://example.com/file.html?r=' . rand(0, 9999);`